# How can I add a new API to the Flash platform for enabling enhanced audio?

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, audio, flex4.5, microphone

***Enhanced audio API***

This feature is available on all supported desktop platforms of Flash Player and AIR.
We have added a new API to the Flash platform for enabling enhanced audio. This feature is available on all supported desktop platforms **NOT MOBILE PLATFORMS** of Flash Player and AIR. The new API is only available in ActionScript 3. You must target Flash Player 10.3 or AIR 2.7 (or later) and SWF version 12 in your authoring environment, and you must update your playerglobal.swc.

The following classes are affected:
Microphone: A new static method was added to this class to create enhanced microphone and read/write properties for configuring enhanced microphone options.
MicrophoneEnhancedOptions: This new class lets you configure enhanced microphone settings.
MicrophoneEnhancedMode: This new class enumerates enhanced microphone operation modes.

You can see about this in- [Best practices for acoustic echo cancellation in Flash Player](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flashplayer/articles/acoustic-echo-cancellation.html)

I have already developed a FMS desktop client using this API(Microphone, MicrophoneEnhancedOptions and MicrophoneEnhancedMode classes). And this client runs well without any noise.

But recent flex sdk(flex sdk4.6) doesn't support this API for mobile platforms.
How can I enhance the microphone on mobile platforms including noise suppression.

Here is my source code:

/*-----------------desktop-----------------*/

```
microphone = Microphone.getEnhancedMicrophone();

if(microphone)
{
    var options : MicrophoneEnhancedOptions = new MicrophoneEnhancedOptions();
    options.mode = MicrophoneEnhancedMode.FULL_DUPLEX;
    options.autoGain = false;
    options.echoPath = 128;
    options.nonLinearProcessing = true;

    microphone.enhancedOptions = options;

    microphone.gain = 85;

    // set codec to speex
    microphone.codec = SoundCodec.SPEEX;
    microphone.encodeQuality = 5;
    microphone.framesPerPacket = 1;
    microphone.rate = 16; 
    microphone.setUseEchoSuppression(true);             
}
```

/*-----------------android-----------------*/

```
microphone = Microphone.getMicrophone();

if(microphone)
{
    //settings
    microphone.rate = 16;
    microphone.gain = 85;
    microphone.setUseEchoSuppression(false);
    microphone.setLoopBack( false );
    microphone.setSilenceLevel( 0, 20000 );                     
    microphone.codec = SoundCodec.SPEEX;
    microphone.encodeQuality = 5;
    microphone.framesPerPacket = 1;         
}
```

How can I make the android code run like desktop?
How can I implement the functions of MicrophoneEnhancedOptions class and MicrophoneEnhancedMode class?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely, you can't. Those APIs are backed by native code which, in the android's flash version, simply isn't there.